# QTableWidget with a masked password column

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Is it possible to mask certains cells containing a password or columns in a QTableWidget that I created using PyQt5. I was not able to find any option here and searching did not bring up any solution.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#hideColumn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to change the displayed text through a delegate:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class PasswordDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            style = option.widget.style() or QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
            hint = style.styleHint(QtWidgets.QStyle.SH_LineEdit_PasswordCharacter)
            option.text = chr(hint) * len(option.text)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 4)
    delegate = PasswordDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    for i in range(view.rowCount()):
        it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        it.setText("password-{}".format(i))
        view.setItem(i, 0, it)
    view.show()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @eyllanesc for that share i actually was able to reuse this on the specific columns in my tableview and elsewhere via

```
class PasswordDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        style = option.widget.style() or QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        hint = style.styleHint(QtWidgets.QStyle.SH_LineEdit_PasswordCharacter)
        option.text = chr(hint) * len(option.text)
```

This makes it so i don't have to hardcode the column in the class but just apply the delegate to a specific column in the tableview or model that i want it applicable on. via `setItemDelegateForColumn` see more about that [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QAbstractItemView.html?highlight=setitemdelegateforcolumn#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.setItemDelegateForColumn)

```
self.password_delegate = PasswordDelegate()
self.tableView_connections.setItemDelegateForColumn(4, self.password_delegate)
```